# Python with Bleak - Pair with a device that requires a pin

Tags: python, bluetooth, python-bleak

I'm attempting to read some characteristics from a Bluetooth device. The device requires a Pin to pair but I can't find any resources on how to enter a pin with python-bleak.

My code is below. It will successfully connect and get the services. Any attempt to bond with the device gives me an error.

> bleak.exc.BleakError: Could not pair with device: 19

Is it possible to pair to a device that requires a pin using python-bleak? If not is there a different way to pair to the device with python?

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient, exc, BLEDevice, backends
from typing import Any, List, Dict

deviceAdress = "zz:yy:xx:ww:vv:uu".upper()

fixedPin = "012345"

async def GetServices(client:BleakClient) -> backends.service.BleakGATTServiceCollection:
    services = await client.get_services()
    return services

async def main():
    device:BLEDevice = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(deviceAdress)
    print(device)

    client:BleakClient = BleakClient(device, timeout=60)
    try:
        connectResults = await client.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    await GetServices(client)          # Successfully gets services

    pairResults = await client.pair()  # Fails here


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Is this a Bluetooth Low Energy or Bluetooth Classic Device?

Comment: It's Bluetooth low energy

Comment: In Bluetooth Low Energy it is usually just some of the services that require authentication (and therefore pairing). See https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html#pairing-bonding. Have you tried to read/write any of the characteristics?